# How do I format my Ubuntu recovery media pendrive?

Tags: format, usb-installation, boot-partition

I got a new laptop with Ubuntu installed and during setup. I was asked if I wished to have a backup. I was asked to use a pen drive with a minimum of 2GB space. I used a 16GB pendrive. After the recovery media was installed. I couldn't access the rest of the pendrive (14GBs). What do I do?
I am unable to format the pendrive nor can I change it's read and write settings. This is my first time using Linux so please do forgive my ignorance. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you format your USB Drive, you will remove the backup that you created, are you OK with that?

Comment: Yes I am. I can get a smaller pendrive to load the backup into

Comment: The, you can check the answer I posted

Comment: Welcome! Why are you unable to format the USB? What have you tried that did not work?

Answer (score 1):

There are several disk manager tools that you can use on Ubuntu. One of the best is GParted, you can install it via Ubuntu Software.
Once it is installed:

1. Plug your USB Drive to your PC
2. Open GParted, enter your password and choose your USB Drive as shown in the screen shot `/dev/sdb` (the top right of the screenshot)

[image]

3. Select all the partitions (the box with green).
4. Go to **Partition** option and select *unmount*.
5. Go the **Device** option and select *create partition table*.
6. Make sure that the partition table type is *msdos*, then click **apply**.
   After that, you will have a grey partition as shown in the screenshot

[image]

7. Select the grey partition and click on **Partition** option again and choose *new*.
8. choose the File system type (in my case I chose NFTS), then press add.
   [image]

   9. Click on the green sign (the OK/Check sign) as shown in the following screenshot and wait till the operation complete.
      [image]