# Repair usb and return the original size of it

Tags: usb

[image]Here is the output of `lsblk`:

```
 lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0    74M  1 loop /snap/wine-platform-3-stable/6
loop1    7:1    0 156.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/110
loop2    7:2    0  54.6M  1 loop /snap/core18/1279
loop3    7:3    0  14.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/359
loop4    7:4    0  89.1M  1 loop /snap/core/8039
loop5    7:5    0 215.2M  1 loop /snap/wine-platform-runtime/62
loop6    7:6    0 215.2M  1 loop /snap/wine-platform-runtime/54
loop7    7:7    0  44.2M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1353
loop8    7:8    0 323.9M  1 loop /snap/pycharm-community/167
loop9    7:9    0 342.1M  1 loop /snap/pycharm-community/169
loop10   7:10   0   4.2M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/501
loop11   7:11   0  89.1M  1 loop /snap/core/8213
loop12   7:12   0   4.2M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/544
loop13   7:13   0    24K  1 loop /snap/acrordrdc/6
loop14   7:14   0   956K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/81
loop15   7:15   0  14.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/367
loop16   7:16   0  54.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/1265
loop17   7:17   0   156M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/91
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  97.1G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0 228.8G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   7.8G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda6   8:6    0  48.8G  0 part /
└─sda7   8:7    0  83.2G  0 part /home
sdb      8:16   1     8M  0 disk 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capacity of pen drive shown is less than the actual](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611325/capacity-of-pen-drive-shown-is-less-than-the-actual)

Comment: Check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1180029/822295)

Comment: If it is a software problem or compatibility problem (let us call it 'confusion'), we can fix it. If it is a hardware problem, there is no tool available to you and me, that can fix it. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035).

Answer (score 0):

I'm I'm understanding this correctly (it's not very clear what you're asking) you have a thumb drive that won't read and reports only the boot record, and you want to repair its file system.

Generally, if formatting or repartitioning a thumb drive doesn't immediately fix it, the best course of action is to toss it in the nearest waste receptacle and buy another.  The cost of these devices, even high end ones, is small compared to the risk of losing data by depending on a "repaired" device that turns out not to have been completely repaired -- and the likelihood of a "repair" leaving a drive that reports good capacity, but loses data immediately (without you being aware of it) is too high to take the risk.